# JQuery onclick doing nothing

Tags: asp.net, jquery

So here is my button:

```
<div id="calculateButton" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/btn_calculate.gif")%>" />
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$('#calculateButton').click(function () {
    alert('Calculating...');
});
```

When I click the button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Edits:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#prepaymentTable").bubble({ width: 400, title: 'Prepayment' });
        $("#exposureTable").bubble({ width: 400, title: 'Exposure' });

        $('#calculateButton').click(function () {
            alert('Calculating...');
        });

    });
```

The bubble plugins both work...but not the button click...

Comment: did you try removing the img and just just clicking inside the div? is the img loading properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're attaching the `click` handler inside a `document.ready` handler, after the element has loaded, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#calculateButton').click(function () {
    alert('Calculating...');
  });
});
```

If it's created *later* as the result of AJAX, etc, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), for example:

```
$('#calculateButton').live('click', function () {
```

Comment: @slandau - are you sure there are no errors before the handler attaches? and is the button both in the DOM (not loaded later) and have a unique ID?

Comment: I'm running firebug and it's showing zero errors. The id is what you see in the <div> above that the function is using...

Comment: @slandau - ah, so the element is being added later :)